# how to create MKCoordinateRegion

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, mkcoordinateregion

How to create MKCoordinateRegion .

```
    NSString *latitudeString =  [locationString substringToIndex:startRange.location];
    NSString *longtitudeString = [locationString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startRange.location+2,((endRange.location-1)-(startRange.location+2)))];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((int)latitudeString, (int)longtitudeString);

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 500, 500);`
```

I get the error "**Invalid Region center:+392128672.00000000, +392128704.00000000 span:+0.00448287, -0.01195557**"

Comment: What is the value of locationString?? What are you getting in latitudeString and longitudeString variables??

Comment: 37.33240869090869||-122.0304678723966||Apple Inc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the type casting. Use below code.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([latitudeString doubleValue], [longtitudeString doubleValue]);
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 500, 500);
```

Comment: Apurv calls doubleValue on the String with parses it and returns a double

Answer (score 1):

If you store your latitude and longitude in a string like this:

```
NSString *latitudeString = @"12.2323";
```

You should convert it to a float, like this:

```
CGFloat latitude = [latitudeString floatValue];
```

And after that, you can this in your

```
CLLocationCoordinate2DMake
```

method, it should work. And the problem comes from, that the latitude can only between -90 and 90, the longitude between -180 and 180 (degree), and your numbers are way bigger than that.